# Kotlin | Merge 2 ArrayList<Int> In a one ArrayList<Int>

Tags: kotlin

I have two `ArrayList<Int>`

And i want a way to merge both of the `ArrayList<Int>` in 1  new `ArrayList<Int>`

Comment: So how do you want to merge them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just instantiate your new `ArrayList` and add all elements from list 1 and 2.

```
var list1 = ArrayList<Int>()
var list2 = ArrayList<Int>()
var list3 = ArrayList<Int>()
list3.addAll(list1)
list3.addAll(list2)
```

Answer (score 9):

it is so easy in kotlin by using the `+` operator, for example:

```
val list1 = arrayListOf(1, 2);
val list2 = arrayListOf(3, 4);
val merged  =  list1 + list2; 
  //  ^--- [1, 2, 3, 4]
```